# Excel 2013, changing percentage values to entire column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm a beginnger in using Excel 2013 here but i do know how to use the basic functions ie. (SUM, PRODUCT, ROUNDUP etc...)

Is it possible to have a function that allows me to calculate various percentage value of cells in a column just by changing the top cell(head)?

For example:

Column A (from row 2 - 100) is prices of various things

Column B (from row 2 - 100) is the discounted prices ie. (95%, 80%, 70%)

I want to insert a function value in Column B row 1 where i can change the percentage discounts ie. (95%, 80%, 70%) and it will apply to the entire Column.

Note: I am using Excel 2013

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: Does column B have prices or percentages? E.g. If cell A2 contains $10, cell B2 contains $5 when cell B1 contains 50%? Or do you want to put 50% in cell B1 and cells B2-B100 become 50%?

Answer (score 2):

As Robbie W commented, there are two obvious interpretations of your question, however both very simple to do in Excel....

**Case 1** - You want all cells in `Column B` to take the same value as that in `Cell B1`

Enter `=$B$1` in `Cell B2` and drag down to all cells in the `B` column:

[image: Formula in B Column Case 1]

**Case 2** - You want all cells in `Column B` to be adjusted according to the price in `Cell B1`

Enter `=$B$1*A2` in `Cell B2` and drag down to all cells in the `B` column:

[image: Formula in B Column Case 2 - 95%]

Here I formatted `Column B` as Currency with the GBP sign. If you change the value of `Cell B1` then the values in the entire `Column B` will automatically adjust.

[image: Formula in B Column Case 2 - 50%]

Note that this assumes you have formatted `Cell B1` as a `Percentage`.

Comment: Case 2 is exactly what i've been trying to do, thanks!!

Comment: No problem, Please mark this answer as an answer to your question so your question is removed from the "unanswered" questions folder.

Comment: Chase, to do that, you need to click on the check mark.  That will "accept" @Kevin 's answer.